# Is there any limitation of Secondary IP address number on a SVI or interface on 450x?

Tags: cisco, cisco-4500

After a search on configuration guide and documentation, I didn't any evidence of a limitation on `ip address secondary`configuration on a certain VLAN on 450x SUP6E.

Anyone know where I can found such information or confirm if is there any ?

By my perception, there is no limitation on secondary IP possible to configure on a SVI or interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no defined maximum limit for the amount of secondary IP addresses. However using a lot of secondary IPs usually points to a poor network design. What is your need for these secondary addresses?

Here is a quote from Ivan Pepelnjak:

> … and pasted the results into the console window. No problem, a router
>   accepted at least 250 secondary addresses. Chris repeated the process
>   on his Catalyst switch and reported that he stopped the test after
>   approximately 150 addresses (obviously way more than what he needed).

[Ivan IOS hints maximum secondary IP](http://blog.ipspace.net/2009/04/secondary-subnets-limitation.html)

Also from Cisco's FAQ:

> Q. What are the maximum number of secondary IP addesses that can be
>   configured on a router interface?
>
> A. There are no limits on configuring secondary IP addresses on a
>   router interface. For more information, refer to Configuring IP
>   Addressing.

[Cisco FAQ](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/28745-44.html#q21)

If you really want to find out then you could test it with a script generating configuration and then pasting it in. My guess is you will get bored before you run into any limit though.

Comment: I wondered whether secondaries consumed an idb, in case you'd hit that limit; I tested with 20 secondaries... apparently they don't consume an idb AFAICT

Comment: Thanks, I will not go further that 10 secondaries so it will be fine.